# php submit returning source code?

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue where after pressing submit, I am taken to a page that is all source code rather than getting logged in like I expected.

Can anyone tell me where my issue is that would be great, I'm really confused i want it working as a local page for now as I am in very early stages of development I am new to the world of coding but am trying to learn.

Source of Index.html:

```
<?php

session_start();
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

if ($_POST['username']) {

$dbUsername = "james";
$dbPassword = "";
$uid = "1111";

$username = strip_tags($_POST["username"]);
$paswd = strip_tags ($_POST["password"]);

if (username == $dbusername && $paswd == $dbPassword){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;

    header("location: index.html");

} else {
    echo "username and password not registered";
}
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Rank Landlord</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body class="body">

<header class="mainHeader">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <br />
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-     data">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> 
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="Submit" /><br /><br />
</form>
</div>
    <nav><ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="xxx.html">XXX</a></li>
        <li><a href="xxxx.html">XXXX</a></li>
        <li><a href="xxxxxxx.html">XXXXXXt</a></li>
        <li><a href="Registration.html">Registration</a></li>
        <li><a href="detailed.html">XX</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
</header>

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">   
            <article class="topcontent">    
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this   POST TITLE">Who are we?</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                </footer>

                <content>
                            <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                           <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                </content>

            </article>

            <article class="bottomcontent"> 
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this           POST TITLE">Registration</a></h2>
                </header>

                    <footer>
                        <p class="post-info">Register as a free user using social media</p>
                </footer>

                <content>
                    <p>social media logos to go here, with links</p>
                </content>

            </article>
         </div>

            <aside class="top-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2>quick search</h2>
                <p></p>
                <div id="bottomContent">
     <form class="searchform cf">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Find a Landlord to RANK!">
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <p> </p>
 </form>
 </div>
                </article>
            </aside>

            <aside class="middle-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2>Area Search</h2>
                <p>
                <form class="searchform cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Postcode..."></p>
                <p>     
                <form class="searchform cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="City..."></p>
                <p> 
                <form class="searchform cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="County..."></p>
                <p><form action="">
                <select name="Within...">
                <option value="01">0-1 Miles</option>
                <option value="25">2-5 Miles</option>
                <option value="5-10">5-10 Miles</option>
                <option value="10plus">10+ Miles</option>
   </select>

                <p>  <button type="submit">Search</button> </p>
                </article> 
            </aside>                
  </form></p>
    </div>

    <footer class="mainFooter">


    </footer>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: When your file name does not have the extension `.php` it will not be executed like an php file.

Comment: **index.html** is trying to serve server side script (PHP). Rename it to **index.php**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the filename from `index.html` to `index.php` otherwise it won't get parsed and executed by PHP.

Also ensure that you are executing the file from a webserver with PHP installed.

Comment: or tell the server to parse this page or all *.html as php as some people like to keep *.html

Comment: You could also do that although it seems overkill when you can just change the file extension. In most cases for SEO people would hide the `index.php` or the file extensions anyway with `mod_rewrite` or something similar.

Comment: I have tried that, all i get is the source code instantly instead of after submitting it i do that.

Comment: @JamesBurnieMcburnie where are you developing this? Are you running the file straight from the filesystem or in a development server like MAMP or EasyPHP?

Comment: @JamesBurnieMcburnie your running this locally or on a host? your accessing file though web server and not just just loading the file in a browser?

Comment: @DanielWaghorn SEO is dead.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith a clean URL structure certainly isn't.

Comment: straight up, not using a server do have Wamp installed but for some reason despite my best efforts and long trawls on the forums it still wont start up the servers

Comment: @DanielWaghorn Agreed, however SEO is not SEO anymore. "clean URL structure" call it CUS and CUS is useful lol

Comment: @JamesBurnieMcburnie then your php code will not work

Comment: @JamesBurnieMcburnie That's why you're having the issue with it not executing. Once you get it running you should be able to drop the file into the web root and it should work. If you're having trouble with WAMP and can't get it to work I definitely recommend [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) as an alternative.

Comment: -10 for not knowing that you actually need a working server to run php

Comment: Ok thanks, i had a feeling this was the issue, but wanted to make sure i hadn't messed up my code, only been doing this for about two weeks, thanks for the help, if that doesn't work i'll let you know.

Comment: if you had SHARED this feeling in the post - you would of saved every one a LOT of time